# Paypal error - You do not have permissions to make this API call

Tags: expresso-store

I'm getting the below error when trying to make a payment in store:

You do not have permissions to make this API call
I've checked and the paypal express settings are all correct and it's pointing to the live server and not testing - do you know why this could be?

Thanks
Guy

Answer (score 1):

Is your PayPal email address confirmed? See [this article at Yahoo!](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/order/paypal/paypal-53.html), also make sure you've switched everything from Sandbox to your actual account. This is more a PayPal error than anything to do with ExpressionEngine, but those are starting points.